# Split every 5000 rows with header into multiple new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to use macro to split my spreadsheet into multiple new files for every 5000 rows and keep the header. I tried this code, but got error message "[image]

Code:

```
 Sub Macro1()
Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, n As Long
    Dim newCSV As Workbook

inputFile = GetOpenFilename

Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)

With inputWb.Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set newCSV = Workbooks.Add

    n = 0
    For row = 2 To lastRow Step 5000
        n = n + 1
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .Rows(row & ":" & row + 5000 - 1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

        'Save in same folder as input workbook with .xlsx replaced by (n).csv
        newCSV.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(inputWb.FullName, ".xlsx", "(" & n & ").csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
End With

newCSV.Close saveChanges:=False
    inputWb.Close saveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Error highlighted from here according to "Debug":

```
Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)
```

Comment: It seems likely that the problem is within `GetOpenFilename`. Put `Debug.Print inputFile` immediately after the assignment (e.g. `inputFile = GetOpenFilename`) and check the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) after the crash to see what is being reported.

Comment: Have you tried `inputFile = Application.GetOpenFilename`  ?

Comment: The Immediate window doesn't show anything when I try this "Sub Macro1()
Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, n As Long
    Dim newCSV As Workbook

inputFile = GetOpenFilename
Debug.Print inputFile

End Sub
"

Comment: Then I tried "inputFile = Application.GetOpenFilename", it opens up finder to look for file. If I select my file, it shows error "Open object failed" and still highlight "Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)"

Comment: I'm not trying to pass the buck when I say I suspect that by now you have corrupt temp files in your `%TEMP% folder. Restart the computer, tap the Windows key and type %TEMP% then hit enter. Delete everything you can from that folder. Some files may be in use but after a reboot you should be able to get an corrupt Excel temp images out of it.

Answer (score 1):

just change it to ActiveWorkbook
unless your planning on running it for a different workbook then the one your using.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, n As Long
    Dim newCSV As Workbook

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set newCSV = Workbooks.Add

    n = 0
    For row = 2 To lastRow Step 5000
        n = n + 1
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .Rows(row & ":" & row + 5000 - 1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

        'Save in same folder as input workbook with .xlsx replaced by (n).csv
        newCSV.SaveAs Filename:=n & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
End With

newCSV.Close saveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

your problem is in the

inputFile = GetOpenFilename

Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)

your not telling it what the getopenfilename is

and there is no need to reopen

use the ACtiveWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you skip the GetOpenFilename option and go for the other one - be specific in this format:

```
"C:\Path\To\ABCDE.xlsx"
```

as detailed by John_w on [MrExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/798404-macro-split-excel-file-multiple-csv-files-every-5000-lines.html).

Comment: I don't know if my path is wrong or what, "/Users/annlll/Downloads/Workbook5.xlsx" says could not be found.

Comment: Alright, path problem is ok, but it ask me to open the file, but it's already open. If I say yes, then it opens again and my macro disappears, if I say no, it's still same error "Open object failed"